# Approval Process Steps Execution

Tags: approval-process

I just wanted to know that is there any possibility where we have created a approval step with an criteria **"record#(name(autonumber) standard field) = null"**

and that steps gets executed.....

Please let me know if anyone have the answer.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

My understanding of your question is, You have a object with Name field as autonumber. You have set approval step as Name!=null. In that case it will be executed for every record.

Mark this as answer if it solves your problem.

Comment: Thanks Sforce.Ninja,
I have mentioned for "=" not for "!=" so the condition is "record#(name(autonumber) standard field) = null"